# Как получить занчения, которые нарушили уникальность при массовой вставке?

Tags: oracle, plsql, constraints

В этом  примере ([DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX Exception](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0480__PL-SQL-Programming/DUPVALONINDEXException.htm)), можно ли получить значения, которые нарушили ограничение, чтобы их можно было записать, например, в лог-таблицу?

Интересно решение, если будет несколько нарушений ограничения в массовой вставке:

```
CREATE TABLE t (ID UNIQUE) AS 
    SELECT 1 ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 ID FROM DUAL
/
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t (ID)
    SELECT 2 ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 ID FROM DUAL;
EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Duplicate value on an index');
END;
/
```

> Duplicate value on an index

Как в блоке исключений получить `ID=2`, которое нарушает уникальность?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Capture values that trigger DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13569107) от участника [@craig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134367/craig)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/13569107

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь [FORALL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-DAF46F06-EF3F-4B1A-A518-5238B80C69FA).

> To allow a FORALL statement to continue even if some of its DML statements fail, include the SAVE EXCEPTIONS clause. When a DML statement fails, PL/SQL does not raise an exception; instead, it saves information about the failure. After the FORALL statement completes, PL/SQL raises a single exception for the FORALL statement (ORA-24381).

С клаузой `SAVE EXCEPTIONS` вместо исключения при первой ошибке, выполнение продолжится, а все исключения сохранятся в массив `SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS`. После выполнения, в случае наличия ошибок, будет вызвано исключение `ORA-24381: error(s) in array DML`. Атрибут элемента массива `SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(iх).ERROR_INDEX`, это индекс DML с ошибкой.

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
declare
    cursor cur is
        select 2 id from dual union all
        select 3 id from dual;
    type currows is table of cur%rowtype;
    cr currows;
begin 
    open cur;
    fetch cur bulk collect into cr;
    close cur;
    declare
        forallexcp exception;
        pragma exception_init (forallexcp , -24381);
    begin 
        forall ix in indices of cr save exceptions
            insert into t (id) values (cr(ix).id); 
        dbms_output.put_line (sql%rowcount||' row(s) inserted.');    
    exception when forallexcp then
        dbms_output.put_line (
            sql%rowcount||' row(s) inserted '||sql%bulk_exceptions.count||' error(s).');    
        for ix in 1..sql%bulk_exceptions.count loop dbms_output.put_line (
            'id='||cr(sql%bulk_exceptions(ix).error_index).id||' sqlerrm='||
            sqlerrm (-(sql%bulk_exceptions(ix).error_code)));
        end loop;
    end;
end;
/
```

> 1 row(s) inserted 1 error(s).
> id=2 sqlerrm=ORA-00001: unique constraint (.) violated