# Преимущества FORALL vs INSERT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, insert

В некоторых частях пакета используется `insert into select from`, а в некоторых - `bulk collect` + `forall insert`.

Если приводить все к одному виду, то какой-то из этих методов имеет преимущество по быстродействию или другим аспектам выполнения, или они совершенно равнозначны?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall

Comment: @MaxU Вы не совсем поняли. В статье идет речь о выполнении DML в цикле. Естественно здесь теряется производительность на переключении контекста. Я же имел ввиду выражение Insert into tbl select * from blt. То есть выполнение одним DML оператором. И его сравнение с Forall.

Comment: у меня нет времени писать полноценный ответ, но если вкратце, то если вы можете себе позволить `INSERT INTO a SELECT ... FROM b` - то это будет самый быстрый вариант. Если же у вас огромные таблицы, которые нужно обрабатывать по частям или слишком маленький REDO/UNDO или другие проблемы, не позволяющие вам запустить `INSERT INTO a SELECT ... FROM b` тогда есть смысл обратиться к циклам и FORALL / BULK COLLECT

Comment: Для вставки в __новую__ таблицу или сразу после выполнения `truncate table tab` (т.е. после того как сбросилась High Water Mark), можно воспользоваться хинтом `+APPEND`  известным как `direct path load` для обхода `buffer cache`,

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: а вообще если бы в Oracle был __универсальный и оптимальный__ метод, то очевидно в других методах отпала бы необходимость и их бы удалили или объявили устаревшими

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Главное отличие - это разные контексты (интерпретаторы) выполнения:

- `FORALL` выполняется в PL/SQL, он передаёт в SQL `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)`, т.е. одиночную вставку и матрицу значений переменных связывания для пакета выполнения.
- `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` выполняется чисто в SQL контексте.

На небольших наборах данных разницы в производительности не будет или она будет незначительной. Если данных много, то, как не трудно догадаться, выполнение без переключения контекста будет производительней и для массовой загрузки таблиц как правило используется `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.

Для чего же тогда нужен `FORALL`? `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` накладывает ряд ограничений, и самое первое из них - при такой вставке невозможно получить автогенерированный первичный ключ:

```
declare
    nl numlist; 
begin
    insert into t1 (memo)  
        select 'memo'||rownum from dual connect by level<=3
    returning id bulk collect into nl;
end;
/
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Это значит, что если нужно в одной транзакции сразу вставлять записи с внешним ключом, то без `FORALL` не обойтись:

```
declare
    nl1 numlist := numlist (10,20,30); 
    nl2 numlist; 
begin
    forall i in 1..nl1.count
        insert into t1 (memo) values ('memo'||nl1(i))  
    returning id bulk collect into nl2;
    forall i in 1..nl2.count
        insert into t2 values (nl2(i), 'child'||nl1(i));
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
select * from t1 join t2 on t2.t1id = t1.id;

        ID MEMO           T1ID MEMO    
---------- -------- ---------- --------
        19 memo10           19 child10 
        20 memo20           20 child20 
        21 memo30           21 child30
```

`FORALL` может также быть приемлимым решением и в других случаях, например, более эффективная [вставка с игнорированием ошибок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1195439/217579) по сравнению с `LOG ERRORS`.

---

Подготовка схемы для примеров:

```
create table t1 (id int generated always as identity primary key, memo varchar2 (96))
/
create table t2 (t1id int not null references t1 (id), memo varchar2 (96)) 
/
create or replace type numlist is table of int
/
```